# Heroku + Apartment PG::Error: ERROR: function pg_stat_statements_reset() does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, postgresql-9.3, heroku-postgres, apartment-gem, pg-stat-statements

I use Apartment gem in Rails 4 to support multi-tenancy in Postgres 9.3.3 on Heroku.

An error is occurred when Apartment gem creates a new tenant.

Deep investigation showed that a schema was created, but no tables inside.

Heroku logs showed an error:

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  function pg_stat_statements_reset() does not exist
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When a new schema is created Postgres is trying to reset stats by executing the function **pg_stat_statements_reset()**

By default, this function can only be executed by superusers  [(from original doc)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/pgstatstatements.html).

Heroku doesn't give you superuser privileges.
So you need to disable extension pg_stat_statements.

**Solution 1 - Quick hot fix directly in DB**

1. Access the Rails Console for your Heroku app:

   heroku run rails c
2. Execute SQL statement in schema *public*:

   ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("DROP EXTENSION pg_stat_statements;")

**Solution 2 - via migration**

1. Check the file *db/schema.rb*. Most probably it contains a line

   enable_extension "pg_stat_statements"
2. Create a migration file

   rails g migration DropExtensionPgStatStatements
3. define self.up method

   def self.up
   disable_extension "pg_stat_statements"
   end
4. apply the migration

   rake db:migrate
5. Now the file *db/schema.rb* should not contain that line
6. Commit changes (schema and migration files) and deploy to Heroku

   rake deploy:production:migrations

Regarding the rake task see [deploy.rake](https://gist.github.com/sseletskyy/9248357)