# Disabling `pg_stat_statements` permanently in ActiveRecord + Postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, heroku, apartment-gem

I use the Apartment gem in Rails 4 to manage mult-tenancy in my Rails app.

As explained by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28452483/2490003), the PG Stat Statments that attempt to execute require superuser privelage, which Heroku does not allow. So I followed the directions to **disable** `pg_stat_statements`.

However the next time I created a migration, I noticed that this line got re-added to the `db/schema.rb` file.

```
enable_extension "pg_stat_statements"
```

How do I configure active record to never re-add that `enable..` line again? I want that permanently disabled.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add a migration with following:

```
def change
  disable_extension "pg_stat_statements"
end
```

Comment: I did try that, twice actually. But later migrations tend to add it back in - it might be the `activerecord` gem that automatically tries to do that